# Catching a LXDE Logout with bash

Tags: bash, lxde, logout

I am using LXDE which runs my custom bash script as I login (defined in ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart). My problem is that this script is not stopped as I logout. It hangs waiting in a *inotifywait* executable.

I tried to catch the signals *SIGHUP, SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT, SIGABRT* but these signals are not generated by LXDE (I have tested the script with kill -1 so that I haven't done anything wrong here).

Is there another possibility to catch the logout?